# setInterval to loop through array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a website where they want a news ticker. Currently, I have a array that populates it, and every x seconds, I want the news story to change.

```
function startNews(stories) {

}
```

I am aware that you can use `setInterval`, but it has to go through a new function and you can't specify certain javascript in the same function to fire when it does.

What are you suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use either `setInterval()` or repeated calls to `setTimeout()`.  That's how you do something in javascript at some time in the future.

There are no limitations on what you can do with either of those timer functions.  What exactly do you think you cannot do that is making you try to avoid them?

Here's a pseudo code example:

```
var newsArray = [];   // your code puts strings into this array
var curNewsIndex = -1;

var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    ++curNewsIndex;
    if (curNewsIndex >= newsArray.length) {
        curNewsIndex = 0;
    }
    setTickerNews(newsArray[curNewsIndex]);   // set new news item into the ticker
}, 5000);
```

or it could be done like this:

```
var newsArray = [];   // your code puts strings into this array
var curNewsIndex = -1;

function advanceNewsItem() {
    ++curNewsIndex;
    if (curNewsIndex >= newsArray.length) {
        curNewsIndex = 0;
    }
    setTickerNews(newsArray[curNewsIndex]);   // set new news item into the ticker
}

var intervalID = setInterval(advanceNewsItem, 5000);
```

Comment: I had a if statement in x (`setInterval("x", 1000);`), and firebug gave me an error.

Comment: `setInterval()` takes a javascript function or string as it's first argument.  It can be either a function name or an anonymous function declaration.  It can also be code in a string, but that is not the best way to do it.  See my example above that I added to my answer that uses an inline anonymous function.

Answer (score 10):

You should whenever possible use setTimeout.  If your function takes longer to run than the interval, you can run into a constant 100% cpu usage situation.

Try this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/wdARC/

```
var stories = ['Story1','Story2','Story3'], 
    i = -1;
(function f(){
    i = (i + 1) % stories.length;
    document.write(stories[ i ] + '<br/>');
    setTimeout(f, 5000);
 })();
```

Replace `document.write` with your function.

Comment: Why 'should' you use setTimeout rather than setInterval